# How to change pagination text or symbols in footable?

Tags: javascript, html, pagination, footable

I am using footable to display table which is populated dynamically. I wanted to customize pagination provided by footable. The pagination symbol for navigating to the first and last page needs to be changed as shown below:

- Navigating to first page : change from “<<” to “|<”.
- Navigating to last page : change from “>>” to “>|”.

I tried the following code. But there was no change in the symbols.

```
<table class="table footable no-border" data-page-navigation=".pagination" data-page-size="10" data-page-first-text="|<">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is wrong (I've done a pull request to correct this though)

You should use:

`data-first-text="|<"`

`<table class="table footable no-border" data-page-navigation=".pagination" data-page-size="10" data-first-text="|<">`

Answer (score 0):

Rummaged in the source code, found property `strings`, which you can specify any content. For example, insert an icon with FontAwesome

```
$('.fooTable').footable({
  paging: {
    enabled: true,
    size: 5,
    strings: {
      first: 'someFirstIcon',
      next: '<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>',
      last: 'someLast Icon'
    }
  }
});
```